# How to write my Oracle Query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This is my Oracle query:

```
SELECT 
    To_char(( Trunc (Next_day (SYSDATE, 'SUN')) - 21 ), 'dd-Mon-yy'), 
    To_char(( Trunc (Next_day (SYSDATE, 'SUN')) ), 'dd-Mon-yy'), 
    To_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-Mon-yy') 
FROM   dual
```

How to write this query in SQL Server Management Studio? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post the result of each column as well.. Not everyone knows Oracle and Sql Server

Comment: Use `GETDATE()` instead of `sysdate`. Use `DATEADD` instead of `Next_day`. Use `CONVERT` instead of `To_char` and `Trunc`. Build it up piece by piece. You're more likely to get help if you show some effort (i.e .try something and post an error)